# The smallest user group to test all providers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search, data-structures

I have an algorithm problem to solve.

**Description**: I have a python dictionary that contains following

```
modules = {"auth_provider_1": [3, 4, 17, 19],
         "auth_provider_2": [1, 6, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 18],
         "auth_provider_3": [0, 7, 11, 12, 15],
         "auth_provider_4": [2, 5, 9],
         "cont_provider_1": [4, 14],
         "cont_provider_2": [8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 17],
         "cont_provider_3": [2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 18],
         "cont_provider_4": [0, 1, 6, 7, 12, 19]}
```

There are two types of modules, auth_provider, and cont_provider.
Each one has **4** different providers. For example, we have 4 auth_providers; **auth_provider_1**, **auth_provider_2**, **auth_provider_3** and **auth_provider_4**.
Each provider has a list that contains which user is using that provider.
each user is using only one auth provider and only one cont provider.
For example;
**user 3** is using **auth_provider_1** and **cont_provider_3**
**user 1** is using **auth_provider_2** and **cont_provider_4**.. and so on.

**Problem**: We want to check all providers with a minimum of a user group. For example, if we want to check what providers are users 0,2,4,8 using we will be checking all providers available. Same way with the users 0,2,4,16 and 0,2,4,13...etc

**What I tried**: Making a list from provider names sorted by their list length. For example;

sorted_list =  ['cont_provider_1', 'auth_provider_4', 'auth_provider_1', 'auth_provider_3', 'cont_provider_2', 'cont_provider_3', 'cont_provider_4', 'auth_provider_2']

Iterating this sorted list, searching each element of its list in the modules dictionary and when it's found in a list I removed the key(provider_name) of that list from the sorted list.

For example from a sorted list, the first element is cont_provider_1 which has the smallest list length (it has only 4 and 14), I wanted to start from the smallest one because I thought it would make more sense. Then I search cont_provider_1 in the modules dictionary.

But when I find the 4 and auth_provider_1 and cont_provider_1 somehow iteration stuck somewhere and gives me this answer

```
sorted_list_after_iteration_is_over = ['auth_provider_4']
min_users = [4, 14, 0, 7, 11, 12, 15]
```

**Question**: What would be the best algorithm for this problem? Am I on the right track? Where I am doing wrong? Any suggestions or help?

here is my whole code

```
modules = {"auth_provider_1": [3, 4, 17, 19],
         "auth_provider_2": [1, 6, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 18],
         "auth_provider_3": [0, 7, 11, 12, 15],
         "auth_provider_4": [2, 5, 9],
         "cont_provider_1": [4, 14],
         "cont_provider_2": [8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 17],
         "cont_provider_3": [2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 18],
         "cont_provider_4": [0, 1, 6, 7, 12, 19]}

providers_sorted_list = sorted(modules, key = lambda key: len(modules[key]))
# ['cont_provider_1', 'auth_provider_4', 'auth_provider_1', 'auth_provider_3', 'cont_provider_2', 'cont_provider_3', 'cont_provider_4', 'auth_provider_2']
test_users = []
for provider in providers_sorted_list:
    search_list = modules[provider]
    for user in search_list: 
        for key, val in modules.items():
            if user in val:
                if not user in test_users:
                    test_users.append(user)
                if key in providers_sorted_list:
                    providers_sorted_list.remove(key)
print(providers_sorted_list) 
print(test_users)
```

Comment: This is the [Set Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), if you consider there to be an element `Ai` for the `i`-th auth provider, an element `Cj` for the `j`-th cont provider, each user is a set containing one of each type of element, and you want to cover the set consisting of all `Ai` and all `Cj`. This problem is NP-hard, meaning no algorithms are known that are much better than exponential-time brute force enumeration of all possibilities. That's too slow for large instances but will be fine for instances of the size you have here.